# KeePass 2.17 fails to start

Tags: applications

I installed the newest Mono framework on Lion. After that I tried installing KeePass 2.17 from http://keepass2.openix.be/. When I try to start the application it probably fails, silently (it looks as if nothing happened). How can I check what happened?

Does anybody know how to use KeePass 2.x on MacOS Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and have a workaround until the developer publishes a fix.

- In your Applications folder, right click on the app and choose Show Package Contents.
- Navigate to the Contents/MacOS folder and open `startkeepass.sh` in TextEdit.

  Change this line:

  `path="/Applications/KeePass2.16.app/Contents/MacOS"`

  to this:

  `path="/Applications/KeePass2.17.app/Contents/MacOS"`

  (Replace the 6 with a 7).
- Save and close.

Now the application should start up.

Comment: If you don't mess around with the content of the application package, opening Terminal and execution `sudo ln -s /Applications/KeyPass2.16.app /Applications/KeypPass2.17.app` should do the trick as well. You may have to remove the link again before installing a new version though.

Comment: That works, and what a silly bug it is :).

Answer (score -1):

I resolved my issues by using [KeepassX](http://www.keepassx.org/) (version 2.0 alpha 4), which appears to have less functions, but is natively integrated in OsX and copy-and-paste works as expected.